# Sql query to find the latest start date when the code was tagged to the employee

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have an assignment table with the union code details as follows -

ASG

```
NUMBER      START_DATE              END_DATE                POSITION            UNION CODE        MANAGER
10          01-JAN-2006             17-AUG-2017             MANAGER             6790             Cyndy
10          18-AUG-2017             10-JUL-2018             SUPER MANAGER       6790             Cyndy
10          11-JUL-2018             31-12-4712              SUPER MANAGER       6791             Cyndy

10          01-JAN-2006             07-AUG-2017             associate           6790             Bali
10          08-AUG-2017             10-JUL-2019             sr. associate       6790             Bali
10          11-JUL-2019             31-12-4712              MANAGER             6790             Bali
```

I tweak the below query such that I can find the first date when the latest union code was tagged to the employee. So the output should look like -

```
NUMBER      START_DATE              POSITION            UNION CODE        MANAGER
10          11-JUL-2018             SUPER MANAGER       6791             Cyndy
10          01-JAN-2006             associate           6790             Bali
```

I am using the below query to find the latest row but I need the first date when the union code was tagged-

```
select NUMBER, START_dATE,POSITION,UNION_CODE,MANAGER from 
asg
where sysdate between start_Date and end_date
```

Comment: Why is your output two rows? Assuming that `NUMBER` is the primary key for an employee then you only have a single employee as all the rows have the value `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest `union_code` and then the earliest `start_date` for each `number` you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY "NUMBER" ORDER BY union_code DESC, start_date ASC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   asg a
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ASG ("NUMBER", START_DATE, END_DATE, POSITION, UNION_CODE, MANAGER) AS
SELECT 10, DATE '2006-01-01', DATE '2017-08-17', 'MANAGER',       6790, 'Cyndy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2017-08-18', DATE '2018-07-10', 'SUPER MANAGER', 6790, 'Cyndy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, DATE '2018-07-11', DATE '4712-12-31', 'SUPER MANAGER', 6791, 'Cyndy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2006-01-01', DATE '2017-08-07', 'associate',     6790, 'Bali'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2017-08-08', DATE '2019-07-10', 'sr. associate', 6790, 'Bali'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2019-07-11', DATE '4712-12-31', 'MANAGER',       6790, 'Bali'  FROM DUAL;
```

*(Assuming that you have 2 employees and they should have different `NUMBER`s)*

Outputs:

| NUMBER | START_DATE | END_DATE | POSITION | UNION_CODE | MANAGER | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2018-07-11 00:00:00 | 4712-12-31 00:00:00 | SUPER MANAGER | 6791 | Cyndy | 1 |
| 11 | 2006-01-01 00:00:00 | 2017-08-07 00:00:00 | associate | 6790 | Bali | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dYxtfYuf)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `NUMBER` to be the employee id:

```
SELECT *
FROM ASG A1
WHERE UNION_CODE = (SELECT MAX(UNION_CODE) FROM ASG A2 WHERE A1.NUMBER = A2.NUMBER)
AND START_DATE = (SELECT MIN(START_DATE) FROM ASG A3 WHERE A1.NUMBER = A3.NUMBER)
```

Comment: This does not return the expected output [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0YKW23Jc) because you are not getting minimum start date for the maximum union code; instead you are separately getting the maximum union code and the minimum start date and there is no correlation.